# Start Bluetooth gui from terminal

Tags: cinnamon, i3, bluez

What is the name of the gui cinnamon uses to create a Bluetooth control panel? Can I start that same app from terminal instead of using bluetoothctl?
I have bluez installed, I've paired my device with this machine. I'd like to run that gui from say dmenu when I'm in i3.

Answer (score 3):

I found it. It's called blueberry and from dmenu I can start it on it's own instead of remembering bluetoothctl commands. =p